# What value of $k$ makes the function $p(s)=k*(2/3)^s$ in a probability function?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

This is for $s=2,3,4,...$ I'm looking at my old notes on probability and my original answer was $k*\frac{1}{1-\frac{2}{3}}=1$ implies $k=1/3$ because the sum of such an infinite geometric series is $\frac{1}{1-x}$ but that is for a series that starts with $1+x$ and the first terms of this series are $x^2+x^3$. Doesn't that change the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Yes: $$\sum_{s\ge 2}\left(\frac23\right)^s=\left(\frac23\right)^2\sum_{s\ge 0}\left(\frac23\right)^s=\left(\frac23\right)^2\frac1{1-\frac23}=\frac43\;,$$ so $k=\ldots\;$?

Comment: 3/4. Thanks. That must be right. But my notes show that k=1/3. My notes must be incorrect.

Comment: @jim: You’re welcome.